# $\frac{n}{1+n}$ converges to 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, solution-verification

In the Euclidean metric space $\mathbb{R}$, the sequence $(b_n)$ defined as $b_n:=\frac{n}{1+n}$, converges to 1.

To show that $(b_n) \to 1$, we need only to show that given $\varepsilon>0$, we can find a natural number $N$ such that for every natural number $n \ge N$ we have $|b_n-1|=|\frac{n}{1+n}-1|=\frac{1}{1+n}<\varepsilon$.

Let $n=\max(1,N)$ and $\varepsilon=1$.

Then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $n \ge N$ and $\frac{1}{1+n}<\varepsilon$.

**Edit**

If $d(b_n,1)=\frac{1}{1+n}<\varepsilon \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\varepsilon}<1+n \Rightarrow n>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}-1 \Rightarrow n \ge \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$.

Let $N=\lceil\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\rceil$, so that $N \ge \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$.

This means that for all $n \ge N$ we have $\frac{1}{1+n} \le \frac{1}{1+N}=\frac{1}{1+\lceil\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\rceil}<\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}=\varepsilon$

Thus $\frac{1}{1+n}<\varepsilon$ and hence $\forall n \ge N$, it follows that $|b_n-1|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: You are not allowed to choose $\varepsilon$ and $n$. But you can choose $N$ depending on $\varepsilon>0$. A good choice is $N:=\lceil\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\rceil+1$.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense given the definition of convergence.

Comment: @Jochen So $N:=\lceil\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\rceil+1 \Rightarrow n \ge 2$ and thus $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $n \ge 2 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{1+n}<\varepsilon$?

Comment: Yes, but this is not the point. For all $n\geq N$ we get
$$\frac{1}{1+n}\leq \frac{1}{1+N}=\frac{1}{2+\lceil \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\rceil}<\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}=\varepsilon.
$$
We cannot fix $N$ at 2 or something else not depending on $\varepsilon$. So your last implication is not true.

Comment: @Jochen but why can't we say $N \ge 2$ if $N:=\lceil\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\rceil+1$?

Comment: You can say it, but it's not enough. If $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{42}$ (you cannot choose it), then $n\geq 2$ is not sufficient, because $\frac{1}{1+n}$ does not need to be smaller than $\varepsilon$. But for $n\geq 43$ we know, that $\frac{1}{1+n}< \frac{1}{42}$

Comment: Got it! Thanks.

Comment: @Jochen please see edit. Is this the correct way to algebraically choose N?

Comment: Yes, it is :) Maybe, it is easier to follow, if we choose $N$ in almost the first line. And then it implies $d(b_n,1)=\frac{1}{n+1}<\ldots<\varepsilon$.